# JavaFX while(true) loop freezes application

Tags: javafx-8

I am having a bit of a problem which I have been beating my head over all night. This app works fine as a Java.swing application but unfortunately for the translation to JavaFX and Java8 things got a bit tricky. Dialog boxes didn't translate well of course but that I got resolved. Where I am beating my head is on the while(true) loop. It cycles through to receive the SUBMIT and ACCEPT message from the server but freezes after that. I have tried System.out.println(); all over the server and client side of the program and have traced the issue to that single point. Any ideas? I started without threads originally but had the same issue. I changed the while(true) loop to while(i < 1) moving the MESSAGE else if statement into it's own while(true) if statement because it is the only thread I need to cycle more than once obviously.

Client File

```
package application;

import java.awt.TextArea;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.SocketException;
    import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Client implements Runnable {


        @FXML
        public static
        TextArea InputTA;
        @FXML
        public static
        TextArea MainTA;
        public static BufferedReader clientIn;
        public static PrintWriter clientOut;
        int i = 1;
        static String readLine;


        @FXML
        public void run(){
            /* 
             * @ALambert
             * 
             * Here we initialize the socket, connect to the server we desire and setup
             * our BufferedReader and PrintWriter
             * 
             */

            final int PORT = 8000;      
            String serverAddress = ServerIPPopup.serverIP;
            try {

                Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, PORT);
                System.out.println("Server Connected");
                clientIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                System.out.println("Buffered Reader Set");
                clientOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                System.out.println("Print Writer Set");
                /* 
                 * @Andrew Lambert
                 * 
                 * In this section we set our Screen Name as well 
                 * as start relaying messages to the server
                 * 
                 */



                 while (true) {
                        String readLine = clientIn.readLine();                      
                        System.out.println("readLine Set");

                         if (readLine.startsWith("NAME")) {     
                             ThreadClass.submittedThread st = new ThreadClass.submittedThread();
                             st.start();
                         }else if (readLine.startsWith("ACCEPTED")) {
                                 ThreadClass.acceptedThread at = new ThreadClass.acceptedThread();
                                 at.start();
                                 continue;
                           }else if (readLine.startsWith("MESSAGE")){
                               ThreadClass.messageThread mt = new ThreadClass.messageThread();
                               mt.start();
                           }
                            }



            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.out.println("UnknownHostException");
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(SocketTimeoutException s){
                System.out.println("SocketTimeoutException");
                //s.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                System.out.println("SocketException");
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();
        //  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //      System.out.println("InterruptedException");
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IOException");
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            /* 
             * @ALambert
             * 
             * 
             */         
        }


        }
```

Server File

```
package application;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.HashSet;


public class Server {

    public static final int PORT = 8000;


    public static HashSet<String> clientNames = new HashSet<String>();


    public static HashSet<PrintWriter> writers = new HashSet<PrintWriter>();


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("The chat server is running.");
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        try {
            while (true) {
                new Handler(listener.accept()).start();
                System.out.println("The chat server recieved a geust");
            }
        } finally {
            listener.close();
            System.out.println("The chat server closed");
        }
    }


    public static class Handler extends Thread {
        public String clientName;
        public Socket socket;
        public BufferedReader serverIn;
        public PrintWriter serverOut;


        public Handler(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }


        public void run() {
            try {


                serverIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
                System.out.println("Buffered Reader Set");
                serverOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                System.out.println("Print Writer Set");


                while (true) {                  
                    serverOut.println("NAME");
                    clientName = serverIn.readLine();
                    if (clientName == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    synchronized (clientNames) {
                        if (!clientNames.contains(clientName)) {
                            clientNames.add(clientName);
                            System.out.println(clientName + " was added to the list");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                serverOut.println("ACCEPTED");
                writers.add(serverOut);
                System.out.println("Name: " + clientName + " was Accepted");

                while (true) {
                    String clientInput = serverIn.readLine();
                    if (clientInput == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    for (PrintWriter writer : writers) {
                        System.out.println("message " + clientInput + " recieved from " + clientName);
                        writer.println("MESSAGE " + clientName + ": " + clientInput);
                        System.out.println("message " + clientInput + " sent to " + clientName);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } finally {

                if (clientName != null) {
                    clientNames.remove(clientName);
                }
                if (serverOut != null) {
                    writers.remove(serverOut);
                }
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ThreadClass File

```
package application;

public class ThreadClass {
    public static class submittedThread extends Thread{
        submittedThread(){      
            Client.clientOut.println(ScreenNamePopup.getName);
            System.out.println("Name: " + ScreenNamePopup.getName + " Submitted");              
    }
    }    
    public static class acceptedThread extends Thread{
        acceptedThread(){
            System.out.println("Name: " + ScreenNamePopup.getName + " Accepted");                               
    }
    } 
    public static class messageThread extends Thread{
        messageThread(){

            System.out.println("Message recieved from Server");                                 
    }
    }
}
```

static void Main

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialogs;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/*
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
public class Main extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        try{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("IRCFXML.fxml"));

        stage.setTitle("CO-OP IRC Project");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 450, 450));
        stage.show();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error loading IRCFXML.fxml!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        launch(args);

    }
}
```

IRCController

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;

import java.util.Optional;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javafx.fxml.LoadException;

public class IRCController{
    @FXML
    public
    TextArea MainTA;
    @FXML
    public
    TextArea InputTA;
    @FXML
    public
    Button reset;
    @FXML
    public
    Button handlerbutton;
    @FXML
    public
    Button submit;
    @FXML
    public
    Button serverButton;
    @FXML
    public
    Button screenNameButton;


    @FXML
    private void initialize() throws Exception{

        InputTA.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                    String oldValue, String newValue) {


            }
        });

        MainTA.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                        String oldValue, String newValue) {


                }


            });     
    }

    @FXML 
    public void handleSubmitButtonAction(){
        String clientOutString = InputTA.getText();
        Client.clientOut.println(clientOutString);
        InputTA.setText("");

    }
    @FXML 
    public void handleServerButton(){
        ServerIPPopup sipp = new ServerIPPopup();
        sipp.run();


    }
    @FXML 
    public void handleScreenNameButton(){
        ScreenNamePopup scpp = new ScreenNamePopup();
        scpp.run();
    }

}
```

ServerIP Popup

```
package application;

import java.util.Optional;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ServerIPPopup implements Runnable{
    public static String serverIP;

    public void run(){
        /*
         * @ALambert
         * 
         * dialog popup to gather the ip address of the server you wish to connect to.
         * 
         * 
         */


            TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog("localhost");
            dialog.setTitle("Server IP");
            dialog.setHeaderText("Server IP");
            dialog.setContentText("Please enter the Server IP");
            Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
            if (result.isPresent()){
                System.out.println("Client Side-Server IP " + result.get());
                serverIP = result.get();
                ScreenNamePopup scp = new ScreenNamePopup();
                scp.run();
            }

    }



}
```

ScreenName Popup

```
package application;

import java.util.Optional;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScreenNamePopup  implements Runnable{
    public static String getName;
    public void run(){

                /*
                 * @ALambert
                 * 
                 * popup dialog box to gather the screen name you wish to use for the chat session
                 * 
                 */             
                TextInputDialog dialogScreenName = new TextInputDialog("Screen Name");
                dialogScreenName.setTitle("Screen Name");
                dialogScreenName.setHeaderText("Screen Name");
                dialogScreenName.setContentText("Choose a screen name:");
                Optional<String> resultScreenName = dialogScreenName.showAndWait();
                if (resultScreenName.isPresent()){
                    System.out.println("Client Side-Screen Name: " + resultScreenName.get());
                    getName = resultScreenName.get();
                    Client client = new Client();
                    client.run();
                }
            }





}
```

I still have a lot of work to do of course on this. I'm taking it a step at a time and after this issue is fixed hopefully I can start working on the next piece of the puzzle (i.e. incorporating the MainTA.append("blah blah blah"); aspects so I can get people talking. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
After some critics I went ahead and cleaned up some issues in my code. Some mistakes were blind attempts to stumble upon the awnser to earlier issues i.e getting the dialogue boxes to work properly or to get the BufferedReader and PrintWriters to work. Others were because I never knew but now do. I researched into the thread blockage and found a method to stop the freeze with a socket.soTimeOut(); but have yet to find the means to get it to reach the MESSAGE portion of the block. I've tried seperating them into seperate threads entirely, changing the while(true) to a while (readLine != null) , commenting out the NAME and ACCEPT portions of both the server and client but for some reason whatever avenue I take to get it to read the MESSAGE portion of the block it seems to freeze the program. I'm going to research more into the sync portion of the server and see if that section of the code may be causing some sort of issues with the client. I don't forsee that being the case but I'm at a loss.

Comment: Too much dump, too little information.

Comment: The `while(true)` freezes your application because the JavaFX Application thread gets blocked. You need to use threads in case you need some background task to be performed continuously.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code review site, but this code has many failings.  Application should not implement Runnable.  Applications should not be controllers.  Separate those concerns into separate files.  Applications should show the stage provided in the start method.  Class names should follow [camel case conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java).  Never sleep the JavaFX application thread.  Never busy wait the JavaFX application thread.  Never modify the JavaFX scene graph off the JavaFX thread.  There are other issues.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. This is how we learn after all. I'm new to this of course and though I am new I am not shy to research, research, and research some more till I can figure out the solution to the problem. Unfortunately my research has mainly came up with swing examples which is becoming outdated. So this is one brick wall I have had trouble overcoming.  I'm quite proud of myself for getting the program to the point it is.  But I'm not too proud to ask for help or take advice as it comes my way.